# bpws:getVariableData() causes fault if no xpath match is found

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel

I wanted to use "bpws:getVariableData()" to assign a value only if the xpath expression find a match. If not, nothing should happen. Unfortunately the bpel processing stops with a fault, if the xpath expression finds no match. Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I found that the oracle BPEL engine provides a feature to ignore missing from data. This Flag can be added to the copy element as follows:

```
<copy bpelx:ignoreMissingFromData="yes|no"/>
```

More info on how to set it in the JDeveloper: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/integration.1111/e10224/bp_manipdoc.htm#SOASE87087

This solves the problem with the fault message that is thrown. However it still does not show the wanted behavior. My intension was that no assignment is done, if the xpath expression cannot be evaluated. Using the bpelx:ignoreMissingFromData flag however assigns the empty string "" to the target.

In my use case I want to merge tow XML documents. I want to assign a new value to an element in document1 only if the element shows up in document2. If not, leave the element in document1 unchanged.

I solved the problem using a transformation instead of a BPEL assign. In the xsl I use the following statement. The transformation gets two XML documents a input. Document1 is referenced via the parameter $parameter_referenceDocument1.

```
<elementName>
  <xsl:if test="xpathInDocument2">
    <xsl:value-of select="xpathInDocument2"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="not(xpathInDocument2)">
    <xsl:value-of select="$parameter_referenceDocument1.xpathInDocument1"/>
  </xsl:if>
</elementName>
```

I know its ugly, but solves the problem. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: In case anybody use `ignoreMissingFromData` flag, in BPEL 2.0 the syntax is `<copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes|no"/>`, without `bpelx` namespace. Here is a good example: http://georgie-soablog.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-avoid-selection-failure-in.html.

Answer (score 0):

No, the BPEL standard requires the engine to throw a selectionFailure in this case. To avoid such situations, make sure you have properly initialized variables and/or validate variable against a schema. Also you may guard an assign activity with an if/switch activity to check for the presence of the element before accessing it. You may also consider writing an custom XPath function that returns a default value in case the demanded element does not exist in the variable. However, I'm not sure if the Oracle BPEL engine supports that.

Comment: I found that the oracle BPEL engine provides a feature to ignore missing from data. This Flag can be added to the copy element as follows:
<copy bpelx:ignoreMissingFromData="yes|no"/>
More info on how to set it in the JDeveloper: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/integration.1111/e10224/bp_manipdoc.htm#SOASE87087

Comment: You are absolutely right, I must have been too tired and forgot about that attribute. It is even defined in the specification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scope around the assign activity and using an exception handler on the scope catch the selectionFailure, the item which will then carry on processing.

In the exception handler you could then assign a default value if required.

To clarify Vanto's statement, the Oracle BPEL engine does support custom XPath functions which would allow you to do that.